# Визуализация перебора всех параметров Grid Search CV

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Хочу написать одну универсальную функцию для перебора всех параметров какого-либо алгоритма по "сетке", которая бы была гибкой в настройке и могла визуализировать свои результаты. 
На вход она должна принимать аргументы:

- X и y,
- алгоритм для оптимизации,
- словарь параметров (Ключ-параметр:значение-массив его значений)
- тип кросс валидации для перебора по решетке,
- метрику качества (например: accuracy, roc_auc).

Она должна показывать один единый график по настройке гиперпараметров, а именно, чтобы на нем отображался каждый гиперпараметр в отдельной ячейке, и результат по одной из метрик в зависимости от увеличения его значения (по X_train и X_test). Так же попутно "принтить" результаты о вычислениях.
Натыкался на много разной инфы на этот счет, но собрать воедино в одну функцию пока так и не получается. Думаю что, такая функция пригодится не только мне, но и всем тем, кто хочет "автоматизировать" свой код. Помогите, кому не сложно. 
Что-то вроде такого, только чтобы еще общий график могла выводить.

```
def MY_tune_model(model, X, y, hyperparams=False, typecv=False, randomsearch=False, metric='accuracy'):
    if not hyperparams:
        print('Hyperparameters not specified!')
        hyperparams = {keys: [model.get_params()[keys]] for keys in model.get_params()}
    if not typecv:
        typecv = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)
    if randomsearch:
        search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_distributions=hyperparams, n_iter=10, random_state=42)
    else:
        search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=hyperparams, scoring=metric, cv=typecv)
    grid_result = search.fit(X, y)
    m = ['mean_test_score', 'std_test_score']
    dfres = pd.DataFrame()
    for metric in m:
        dfres[metric]=grid_result.cv_results_[metric]
    for param in hyperparams:
        dfres[param]=[sets[param] for sets in grid_result.cv_results_['params']]
    dfres['dict_params'] = [params for params in grid_result.cv_results_['params']]
    print("Best: %f using %s\n" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
    return dfres, grid_result.best_params_
```

Comment: что значит `тип перебора по решетке`? ЕМНИП все остальное `GridSearchCV` уже умеет...

Comment: Хотелось бы соединить просто все в одну функцию,а то много примеров в интернете, в которых методы GridSearchCV устарели, да и как построить график на котором бы все сразу гиперпараметры отображались тоже не могу разобраться.

Comment: График врядли получится построить, т.к. скорее всего он будет многомерным. По-моему все из того что вы хотите получить ( кроме визуализации) GridSearchCV умеет делать

Comment: Например, в seaborn можно построить график pairplot, чем больше столбцов, тем ячейки на графике меньше в размере

Comment: [такой вариант решения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49117755/5741205) вам подойдет?

Comment: В вопросе привел пример того, что я имелл ввиду, только надо бы еще график добавить.